# Does only "supply/demand" rule justify different prices for a digital good?

Tags: currency

Provided the network infrastructure costs the same for the seller (if things going on with net neutrality weren't to effect that), certainly considering the fact that an average citizen of a given "low average $ income" country would have less money available for digital products than say someone from Germany or U.S.A.

What are the mechanisms that justify large price differences between different countries (3x ratios or more) ?

Edit: Thanks for your answers.
As real life examples, what struck me is any app here https://steamdb.info/apps/ but as you suggested it applies for various digital goods on amazon and other sellers.

Comment: Could you provide specific examples where that disparity happens?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for?  The term 'justify' suggests you may be looking for something different from an explanation.  Are you, for example, asking whether the price differences could be justified as raising overall welfare?

Comment: English isn't my native language, so please forgive the lack of accuracy with words, I simply meant it as "explaining" why the prices difference, and as mechanisms so that I could easily understand it. An advanced economic answer I couldn't comprehend, I'm a lambda human :)

Answer (score 4):

One explanation would be **price discrimination**.

Some people are willing to pay more for software than others. (Typically, we would expect such people to live in richer countries.) As a result, it will be in the interest of software seller with monopoly power to charge different people different prices.

In case this isn't clear, here is an illustrative example. Suppose that Microsoft is deciding how much to charge users for a digital copy of Microsoft Office. Legally, it is the only entity that is permitted to sell Office, so it has some monopoly power. Since we are considering digital copies of Office, its marginal cost will be essentially zero. Suppose that:

- In Country A, all inhabitants would pay at most £10 for one copy of Office.
- In Country B, all inhabitants would pay at most £200 for one copy of Office.

(Assume that no inhabitant wants more than one copy.)

What prices should Microsoft charge (to maximise profits)? Obviously, it should charge £10 in Country A (or £9.99 if you prefer) and £200 in Country B. Thus, even though the cost of production are the same in both countries, prices will vary greatly between them.

Note that this explanation only works if Microsoft can prevent resale - which it can, since it has a patent for Microsoft Office. Otherwise, someone might start buying copies of Office in Country A and re-selling them in Country B, a strategy which will render Microsoft bankrupt unless it changes its pricing.

Of course, it also assumes that price discrimination is legal.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the mechanisms that justify large price differences between
>   different countries (3x ratios or more) ?

Absent any concrete examples where that actually occurs, I can think of some factors that might make sense of the *hypothetical* disparities.

A government might impose *taxes/tariffs on imports*, including digital goods. Providers of a digital good will not absorb those taxes and tariffs. Instead, providers will pass them to the consumer, especially if those providers have access to other (international and/or domestic) markets.

The level or intensity of *competition* might vary per country. Strong competition could prompt a provider to set lower prices in economies where his market share is at risk or reduced.

In the case of digital services, there might be costs associated with *customizing* them to consumers in a foreign economy. Consider the hypothetical situation of a German company offering a digital service to consumers in Spain. Since a large sector of Spain's population only speaks Spanish, the German company might need to hire Spanish speakers for customer support. The resulting, additional cost should be reflected only in the pricing for Spain, lest the company lose market share in the other economies.

Answer (score 0):

I bring a real example for this topic.

There is a e-book called "Open Economy Macroeconomics in Developing Countries (The MIT Press)". I searched it in amazon.es (Spanish Amazon site) and in amazon.com.br (Brazilian Amazon site). These were the results:

[Price in Spain](https://www.amazon.es/Economy-Macroeconomics-Developing-Countries-Press-ebook/dp/B00G4J2EPA): 47.99€. 
[Price in Brazil](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G4J2EPA): 405,31R$ (96.66€ at the time of writing this post).

As we can see, Brazilian people are paying about the **double** of the price which Spanish people are paying. How can we explain this if this is a digital product with no extra cost per sale?

1) Brazilian taxes are higher than Spanish taxes. So here the buyers will pay the difference.

2) The Brazilian Real (currency of Brazil) is a bit volatile, so the seller wants to protect himself against a sudden devaluation of Brazilian Real. So here the buyers will pay this kind of insurance too.

If we add 1 (higher taxes) and 2 (insurance against potential devaluation) we probably have the difference between Brazilian and Spanish prices for the same digital product.

However, this example is not that "simple". If we pay attention, there is the possibility for Spanish buyers to buy the paper-edition of the book (103.51€), but not for Brazilian ones. This could be the third (3) reason of the difference we see between prices. In addition to reason 1 and reason 2, we could add reason 3: Brazilian customers can only buy this product in its digital version, so the seller expects them to be willing to pay more for the same (digital) product since there is no paper-edition alternative (as there is in Spanish case).

So finally, 1 + 2 + 3 could explain the huge difference between the two prices for the same digital product.

In each new example it can be different, but those reasons could explain many other examples.

EDIT: For some reason it does not allow me to link the Brazilian site properly. Anyway, you can just check it at amazon.com.br

Comment: I'm late but these are good points, thank you